# Wrong array order after Schema.where().in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Look at the example: http://pastie.org/5901177

In that code I create 3 clients and push them into user.clients array. After that I added one more client on a top of user.clients array. So when I do

```
Client.where('_id').in(user.clients)
```

I'm getting clients in wrong order. Look at this please via console. 
Does anybody know what's problem in my code?

Comment: Great example code!  Made it very easy to figure out what you were looking for.

Comment: :) No, that was totally serious.  There are so many times people post questions with only the vaguest detail, and having a fully working program was such a treat I had to comment.

Comment: Thanks. I've asked because I don't understand english humor :)

Comment: Can you help with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the returned documents is not affected by the order of the array elements of the `$in` operator used to identify them in a `find`.

You always need to explicitly sort if you want a specific document order from a `find`.

Comment: But how can I set a sorting for my example?

Comment: @Erik You can't sort by an array order directly in mongo like you're trying.  If you can't express the sort you need as a normal field sort order, you have to sort it yourself in code.

Comment: But how can I find out a correct sorting? Can you provide a code for resolving my problem?

Comment: That's an awkward bit of code.  Have you considered reworking your schema to include a field that you can sort on instead of relying on array order?